# slow serial "for" with openmp enabled

Tags: c++, openmp

I try to use openmp and find strange results.

Parallel "for" run faster with openmp as expected. But serial "for" run much faster when openmp disabled (without /openmp option. vs 2013).

Test code

```
    const int n = 5000;
    const int m = 2000000;
    vector <double> a(n, 0);

    double start = omp_get_wtime();
    #pragma omp parallel for  shared(a) 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        double StartVal = i;

        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) 
        {
            a[i] = (StartVal + log(exp(exp((double)i))));
        }
    }

    cout << "omp Time: " << (omp_get_wtime() - start) << endl;

    start = omp_get_wtime();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        double StartVal = i;

        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
        {
            a[i] = (StartVal + log(exp(exp((double)i))));
        }
    }

    cout << "serial Time: " << (omp_get_wtime() - start) << endl;
```

Output without /openmp option

```
0
omp Time: 6.4389
serial Time: 6.37592
```

Output with /openmp option

```
0
1
2
3
omp Time: 1.84636
serial Time: 16.353
```

Is it correct results? Or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Enabling OpenMP might inhibit certain kinds of compiler optimisations. Are you running with Release or with Debug code? The inner loop is redundant and should not really make it into the binary in release mode.

Comment: output for Release mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe part of the answer lies hidden in the architecture of the computer you run on. I tried running the same code another machine (GCC 4.8 on GNU+Linux, quad Core2 CPU), and over many runs, found a slightly odd thing: while the time for both loops varied, and OpenMP with many threads always ran faster, the second loop never ran significantly faster than the first, even without OpenMP.

The next step was to try to eliminate a dependency between the loops, allocating a second vector for the second loop. It still ran no faster than the first. So I tried reversing them, running the OpenMP loop after the serial one; and while it still ran fast when multithreaded, it would now see delays when the first loop didn't. It's looking more like an operating system behaviour at this point; long-lived threads simply seem more likely to get interrupted. I had taken some measures to reduce interruptions (niceness -15, specific cpu set) but this is not a system dedicated to benchmarking.

None of my results were anywhere near as extreme as yours, however. My first guess as to what caused your large difference was that you reused the same array *and* ran the parallel loop first. This would distribute the array into caches on all cores, causing a slight dilemma of whether to migrade the thread to the data or the other way around; and OpenMP may have chosen any distribution, including iteration i to thread i%threads (as with `schedule(static,1)`), which probably would hurt multithreaded runtime, or one cacheline each which would hurt later single threaded reading if it fit in per-core caches. However, all of the array accesses are writes, so the processor shouldn't need to wait for them in the first place.

In summary, your results are certainly platform dependent and unexpected. I would suggest rerunning the test with swapped order, the two loops operating on different arrays, and placed in different compilation units, and of course to verify the written results. It is possible you've found a flaw in your compiler.

Comment: I would have waited until the OP confirmed that he's compiling in Release mode. I find it hard to believe that filling an array of with only 5000 doubles with `log(exp(exp((double)i)` should take six seconds on modern processors.

Comment: Using different vectors for serial and parallel loops eliminates the problem